# Decrease WGET Download Completion Time

Tags: bash, ubuntu, download, wget

I am using the wget program in Ubuntu LTS to download a series of files daily from a web server. Recently, this web server has become overwhelmed, and the organization in charge (NCEP) of maintaining it appears to have started throttling number of download requests and speeds.

Main tipoff: Before this, wget was able to complete a download of all files in under 15 minutes. This process now takes several hours.

The server URL: ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.20210212/00/

The files: gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f${i} (I must download them in their entirety)

My wget request is rather simple inside a for loop loop, which is as follows:

```
for i in {006..240..6}
  do
    wget -O /path/to/file/${ymd}/gfs.t${run}z.pgrb2.0p25.f$i ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.${ymd}/${run}/gfs.t${run}z.pgrb2.0p25.f$i
    # Other Commands After wget Request Completed Here
  done
```

I have also attempted using the aria2c program in place of wget, but have found little difference in completion time. I have debated wrapping all of these files in a text file and passing this list to wget, pausing my downloads every 15 seconds, etc.

Is there an effective way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `Is there an effective way` Buy faster internet.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am told my machine is operating on a dual fiber optic cable setup, each with speeds of 1 Gbps up/down. Normally that would have been my first concern, but likely not the issue here.

Comment: Then `aria2c` can download files in parallel. Hope you didn't just "replace wget with aria2c", that's not the point.

Comment: I did (hopefully) cover my bases prior to this: `${aria2c} -x2 --disk-cache=0 -d /path/fo/files/${ymd}/ ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.${ymd}/${run}/gfs.t${run}z.pgrb2.0p25.f$i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to have multiple files download at the same time? I did not test it with your server, but lets say you download 5 files at the same time, it's going roughly 5 times as fast (assuming you are not reaching your or their max internet speed).

An implementation could look like:

```
for i in {006..240..6}; do
  # Notice the & at the end of the next line. It's to start the wget process in a background thread. Our current thread just continues without waiting for wget
  wget -O /path/to/file/${ymd}/gfs.t${run}z.pgrb2.0p25.f$i ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.${ymd}/${run}/gfs.t${run}z.pgrb2.0p25.f$i &
  # Sleep until we have less than 5 running wget jobs at the same time
  while [ $(jobs | wc -l) -ge 5 ]; do
    sleep 1
  done
done
for i in {006..240..6}; do
  # We have all the files downloaded. Now do something with them.
  echo Other Commands After wget Request Completed Here
done
```

Comment: Ahh running the wget requests in parallel, I follow what you've written here and I like the idea, thanks @Veda! I like the sleep command to cap the requests at 5, didn't even think of that.

Comment: Initial testing shows this is considerably faster, I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks again!